# Java takes 2 bytes to represent character?

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, byte

In general a character is represented in 1 byte i.e. 8 bits . This is I believe true for all text editors even for databases like oracle. 1 byte
can represent 2^8 = 256 Characters.
My question is when character can be represented in 1 byte why java takes 2 bytes to represent character ? What is the reasoning behind it.

Comment: "1 byte can represent 2^8 = 256 Characters" Well what if you have more than 256 characters?

Comment: You mean unicode characters ?

Comment: @user3198603, that assumption has not been true for nearly 3 decades now.  Don't forget that Asian nations like Japan and China have well over 256 characters.  Most modern databases and programming languages have been using some form of UTF for a long time now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java was developed after [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/) was invented.  So it uses 16 bit words to handle up to 65536 different characters.  Unicode is intended to handle many character sets in addition to Roman letters - such as Greek or Cyrillic.

Unfortunately, the Unicode consortium didn't realise that 65536 characters wasn't going to be enough.  So they have now extended it to 21-bit characters.  This leaves Java to use UTF-16 encoding for its characters, which is a horrible bodge without either the cleanness of UTF-32 or the compactness of UTF-8.

Comment: I'll also add that it's not the only language to do that. .NET languages also use UTF-16 for their internal character representation.

Comment: @BgrWorker .Net does that because Windows NT went from UCS-2 to UTF-16 too, and it's a MS design.

Comment: As an addendum to this answer: Java provides methods like `Character.isSurrogate(char ch)` to check whether one Java-character (= UTF16 code unit) is _half_ of an encoded Unicode code point, and related methods to get the code point as an int. Because of these surrogate pairs, string operations like `length()`, `charAt()` and `substring()` are really tricky (i.e. can give “wrong“ or corrupted results). The simple interview question “how do you reverse a string?” is also complete horror when considering surrogate pairs (or other Unicode specialties like combining characters or bidi-marks).

Comment: Swift standard library is flexible: It uses either ASCII or UTF-16. But that’s the representation only. Character = extended graphemes cluster. Lots of characters consist of more than one Unicode code points.

Comment: It's worth noting that since your answer was posted [JEP 254: Compact Strings](https://openjdk.org/jeps/254) was implemented in Java 9. The effect of that change was to internally store Latin-1 characters (i.e. those <= 255) in a single byte rather than two. So the _"horrible bodge"_ has become even more horrible, though the enhancement itself is entirely reasonable and understandable.